# Regex PowerShell: Replace every comma with [blank] if it doesn't have a value in between a comma

Tags: regex, powershell

**Regex PowerShell**: Replace every comma with [blank] if it doesn't have a value in between a comma.

**Raw Data**:

```
Name 1,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported
Name 2,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,
Name 3,Exported,Exported,,Exported,Exported,,
```

**Expected Output**:

````
Name 1,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported
Name 2,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,[Blank]
Name 3,Exported,Exported,[Blank],Exported,Exported,[Blank],[Blank]

This is what I got so far:
```powershell
$data -replace ("(,\W)|(,\s)", ",[Blank],")
````

However, it doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a pattern, you could use

```
(?m),[^\S\r\n]*(?=,|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?m)` Inline multiline modifier
- `,` Match a comma
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ times a whitespace char without a newline
- `(?=,|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right is either a comma or the end or the line

And replace with

```
,[Blank]
```

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fm%29%2c%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*%28%3f%3d%2c%7c%5cr%3f%24%29&i=Name+1%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%0d%0a%0d%0aName+2%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%2cExported%2c%0d%0a%0d%0aName+3%2cExported%2cExported%2c%2cExported%2cExported%2c%2c&r=%2c%5bBlank%5d) | [Powershell demo](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyUlsSTR1kGdyy8xN1XBUMe1oiC/qCQ1hTwGF8QYIzKNgWo3xiKFTYhL3YEL7H4F3aLUgpzE5FQFDSUN@1xNnei4mOCYopi8WC0Ne1udGhVNJR0FJZ1op5zEvOxYJc3//wE)

[image]

For example

```
$data=@'
Name 1,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported

Name 2,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,

Name 3,Exported,Exported,,Exported,Exported,,
'@
$data -replace ("(?m),[^\S\r\n]*(?=,|$)", ",[Blank]")
```

Output

```
Name 1,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported

Name 2,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,Exported,[Blank]

Name 3,Exported,Exported,[Blank],Exported,Exported,[Blank],[Blank]
```

Comment: Nice. It worked like a charm. I was doing this for an hour now :) Thanks!